# I am looking for a SFMC Data Dictionary template

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am looking for a SFMC Data Dictionary template. I have found many resources for Salesforce specific data dictionary but looking for a format that fits SFMC data.

Answer (score 1):

The data views reference [Subscribers](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_subscribers.htm&type=5), [Lists](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_lists.htm&language=en_us&type=5) and [Publication Lists](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_publication_lists.htm&type=5) that have a standard schema, but the other views are for send and post-send activity.  I use [dataviews.io](https://dataviews.io/) for reference, as well as Cam Robert's [dbdiagram.io](https://dbdiagram.io/d/SFMC-Data-Views-5ff259ed80d742080a34e3c3).

Is there an ideal data schema for SFMC?  It's whatever you want it to be, *in addition to* Subscribers and Lists.  SFMC instances integrated with a Salesforce CRM org are exposed to the Salesforce Object data via [MC Connect](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_marketing_cloud_connect.htm&language=en_US&type=5), but the relationship between that data and the SFMC data model is generally Subscriber Key <-> Contact ID. The best illustration I've seen of this is [this diagram by Mark Cane of Audit9](https://audit9.blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/salesforce-marketing-cloud-developer.pdf).

Beyond the system data views, understanding the [SOAP API objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/soap_web_service_objects.html) will inform you on the data components of how SFMC works.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to Salesforce Sales Cloud (CRM), Salesforce Marketing Cloud doesn’t come with predefined data model. Setting up all data entities is up to you and your use cases.

The only predefined elements are the data views, which you can read more about here: https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/config/sfmc-system-data-views/